# How to use Magento REST services

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community, rest-api, web-services

I am trying to use **Magento's rest services**, trying to follow the example on http://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/ and http://inchoo.net/magento/consuming-magento-rest-zend_oauth_consumer/. I have a Magento store installed on localhost over WAMP server.

Basically what I did is:

1. Add user roles, create oAuth consumer, and enable access to attributes, in Magento's admin, as explained in the link
2. I created a new module, under app/code/local/Inchoo, named RestConnect, with the folders 'Block', 'controllers', 'etc', 'Helper', 'Model', 'sql'.
3. Inside 'controllers' folder, I created a file named TestController (previously I had named it IndexController), with the following code:

   ```
   <?php

   class Inchoo_RestConnect_TestController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

   public function indexAction() {

   //Basic parameters that need to be provided for oAuth authentication
   //on Magento
   $params = array(
       'siteUrl' => 'http://127.0.0.1/mystore/index.php/oauth',
       'requestTokenUrl' => 'http://127.0.0.1/mystore/index.php/oauth/initiate',
       'accessTokenUrl' => 'http://127.0.0.1/mystore/index.php/oauth/token',
       'authorizeUrl' => 'http://127.0.0.1/mystore/index.php/admin/oAuth_authorize',//This URL is used only if we authenticate as Admin user type
       'consumerKey' => 'h7n8qjybu78cc3n8cdd5dr7ujtl33uqh',//Consumer key registered in server administration
       'consumerSecret' => '2smfjx37a6e4w23jlcrya6iyv5v32fxr',//Consumer secret registered in server administration
       'callbackUrl' => 'http://127.0.0.1/mystore/index.php/restconnect/test/callback',//Url of callback action below
   );

   // Initiate oAuth consumer with above parameters
   $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($params);
   // Get request token
   $requestToken = $consumer->getRequestToken();
   // Get session
   $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
   // Save serialized request token object in session for later use
   $session->setRequestToken(serialize($requestToken));
   // Redirect to authorize URL
   $consumer->redirect();

   return;
    }

   public function callbackAction() {

   //oAuth parameters
   $params = array(
       'siteUrl' => 'http://127.0.0.1/mystore/index.php/oauth',
       'requestTokenUrl' => 'http://127.0.0.1/mystore/index.php/oauth/initiate',
       'accessTokenUrl' => 'http://127.0.0.1/mystore/index.php/oauth/token',
       'consumerKey' => 'h7n8qjybu78cc3n8cdd5dr7ujtl33uqh',
       'consumerSecret' => '2smfjx37a6e4w23jlcrya6iyv5v32fxr'
   );

   // Get session
   $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
   // Read and unserialize request token from session
   $requestToken = unserialize($session->getRequestToken());
   // Initiate oAuth consumer
   $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($params);
   // Using oAuth parameters and request Token we got, get access token
   $acessToken = $consumer->getAccessToken($_GET, $requestToken);
   // Get HTTP client from access token object
   $restClient = $acessToken->getHttpClient($params);
   // Set REST resource URL
   $restClient->setUri('127.0.0.1/mystore/index.php/api/rest/products');
   // In Magento it is neccesary to set json or xml headers in order to work
   $restClient->setHeaders('Accept', 'application/json');
   // Get method
   $restClient->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);
   //Make REST request
   $response = $restClient->request();
   // Here we can see that response body contains json list of products
   Zend_Debug::dump($response);

   return;
    }

    }
   ```
4. Inside 'etc' folder, I created config.xml, with the following code:

   ```
   <config>    
   <modules>
       <Inchoo_RestConnect>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Inchoo_RestConnect>
   </modules>
   ```
5. And finally, in app/etc/modules, I created Inchoo_RestConnect.xml:

   ```
   <config>
   <modules>
       <Inchoo_RestConnect>
           <active>true</active>
           <codePool>local</codePool>
       </Inchoo_RestConnect>
   </modules>
   ```

Then I tried to access http://127.0.0.1/mystore/index.php/api/rest/test, as is said in the link, but I don't get the expected result.

I am new to using Magento and REST, and I'm aware I could be missing or misunderstanding something; could you please tell me if you see any error, or I'm missing something in the process?

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: You may have already fixed this, but I noticed your xml files didn't have a closing </config> tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I actually have the closing tags, however I didn't paste them here by mistake.

Comment: No probs. 

I actually managed to get this working, but I'm away from my computer til next week so I can't post it. However, i *think* it was to do with oAuth needing to be lowercase (oauth). I noticed you have it camel case where it says "authorizeUrl". 

Something to do with cases anyway - that's what solved my problem! :)